# Is it possible to make a mock Chartreuse liqueur?

Tags: ingredients, liqueur

The [Grande Chartreuse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grande_Chartreuse), just north of the city of Grenoble, France has been making Chartreuse since 1737 and is made with **130 herbs**, plants and flowers. Talk about drinking to your health, some say this is an excellent medicinal liqueur. Here in Canada, the Chartreuse liqueur is very expensive.

> The two types of Chartreuse are:
>
> Green Chartreuse (110 proof or 55%) is a naturally green liqueur made from 130 herbs and plants macerated in alcohol and steeped for about 8 hours. A last maceration of plants gives its colour to the liqueur.
>
> Yellow Chartreuse (80 proof or 40%), which has a milder and sweeter flavour and aroma.

The actual recipe for the Green Chartreuse is known to only two Charthusian monks and is aged for five years, so no wonder it is so expensive.

> The two monks charged with the duty oversee the entire production of Chartreuse. It begins in the monastery's herb room where the precise selection of herbs is bagged. These are then taken to the distillery and macerated with a neutral alcohol spirit which is then distilled. - [What is Chartreuse Liqueur?](https://www.thespruce.com/about-chartreuse-liqueur-760267)

Does anyone know of a mock recipe for the Chartreuse Liqueur of 130 herbs?

[image: Chartreuse Green Liqueur (750ml)]

[Chartreuse Green Liqueur (750ml)](https://www.drinkupny.com/Chartreuse-Green-Liqueur-p/s0081.htm)

Comment: Sorry, I'm going to repost this guy's step by step instructions, but he did a very in-depth recreation of Chartreuse on Instructables http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-Make-a-Green-Chartreuse-Clone/

Comment: That should be I'm NOT going to repost

Comment: I also like the appoach that the [Drunken Botanist](http://drunkenbotanist.com/travel/diy-chartreuse-or-something-like-that/) takes, particularly the concept that, if it grows in the area, toss it in.

Comment: @farmersteve Your comment is an excellent answer.

Comment: I don't know if it helps at all, but it sounds very similar to Génépi which could possibly be a lot cheaper as it does not need to be made in a specific way or my monks and aged for 5 years!

Answer (score 2):

I recently made a chartreuse clone by diluting everclear to 110 proof.  Then add 3 tbsp juniper berries, 2 tsp herbs de Provence, tsp fennel seeds, 4 peppercorns, tsp coriander seeds’ 1 bay leaf, and 3 mint leaves.  Let stand for a week a filter. Add 1 cup sugar. The recipe is for a fifth.